# Receiving the commit id with Jenkins (GitHub plugin)

Tags: git, github, jenkins

When we push some changes to github we can use Github services to trigger a build. Does the service provide the commit id?

Do you know how I can get that information?

I need the commit it to trigger the build for that specific id. (Passing the commit id in the field "Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') ").

As described here [git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository) but seems I'm not receiving the commit id from git.

I see my commit id in the post build actions, but not at the moment of the cheking out the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the Git Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to check out your code in Jenkins, then you should be able access the GIT_COMMIT environment variable during any build steps.

There are other useful environment variables defined as well (GIT_BRANCH, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT, etc.) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Yes, I can see the env variable, but I need that information before the code been checked out. I edited the question.

Comment: So you want a git commit to trigger a build, but you don't want it to build unless you know the commit id? I'm not quite clear on the use case here, but if you really need to know the commit id before checking out code, then you could get the commit id in an upstream project and pass it to a downstream project using a build parameter.

Comment: In the link there is an explanation to the use case:

"<commit ID is optional. If set, it will trigger a build immediately, without polling for changes. The advantage of this is that you then can have all pushes tested by jenkins, even when developers push at the same time."

That is why I need the commit id... i mean it works without, but I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub webhooks UI doesn't provide the possibility to pass in parameters to the `/git/notifyCommit` URL, such as the commit SHA1.

There is however the GitHub service "Jenkins (GitHub plugin)" which passes a JSON payload to Jenkins for each commit, containing a bunch of information, including the commit SHA1.

If you enable, under Build Triggers, the "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" option, you may get the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: in the Build session I can see my GIT_COMMIT env var, but would be nice to have that information in the Source Code Management session.