# Groovy script Logic to get commit author id

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Logic in groovy scripts jenkins to get commit author id

Trying that was found in google failed

Comment: What you have tried? How it failed?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68221479/jenkins-pipline-get-latest-successful-commit-id-and-pass-in-another-pipeline or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328869/receiving-the-commit-id-with-jenkins-github-plugin help?